# How to handle sessions in django app when deployed in aws lambda

Tags: django, amazon-web-services, zappa

I want to deploy Django application in aws using Zappa. In my local server sessions are working fine.Is it possible to handle same sessions in aws ? if not is there any method to handle sessions in aws(Zappa)?

-TIA

Comment: What code you have written for managing session in serverless application?

Comment: i have used sessions like this request.session['variable']=1080 in django application. when deployed in aws i couldn't access this session variable.i havent used anything specifically for sessions in aws.

Comment: Ideally sessions should not be used in serverless applications as they are shorlived and stateless. I am not sure how you could make it work locally but on AWS Lambda it will not be working for sure.

Comment: Usually DynamoDB is the go-to for storing session data that is obtained/created by Lambda functions, maybe trying looking at that: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Introduction.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most session capabilities inherent to Django will work fine with a zappa deployed project.

- [Database-backed](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/http/sessions/#using-database-backed-sessions) sessions work fine with no changes
- [Cache-backed](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/http/sessions/#using-cached-sessions) sessions work fine with no changes
- [File-backed](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/http/sessions/#using-file-based-sessions) sessions will ***not*** work due to the inability to guarantee the session file will exist on the lambda container that is handling the user's request
- [Cookie-backed](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/http/sessions/#using-cookie-based-sessions) sessions will work fine with no changes

Ensure the needed infrastructure is available as per the documentation. 
For example if you choose database-backed session, then your Django deployment must have access to a database.